# XSL Transormation for IEEE LOM XML with duplicate namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am trying to transform an XML document with duplicate inline namespace declaration of lom. The document contains among others the following:

```
 <metadata>
   <schema>http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM/imslode/ilox/any/rights</schema>
   <lom xmlns="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM/imslode/ilox/any/rights" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM/imslode/ilox/any/rights http://www.imsglobal.org/profile/lode/lodev1p0/lodev1p0_ilox_any_rights_lom_v1p0.xsd">
      <rights>
         <cost>
            <source>costValues</source>
            <value>no</value>
         </cost>
         <copyrightAndOtherRestrictions>
            <source>copyrightAndOtherRestrictionsValues</source>
            <value>yes</value>
         </copyrightAndOtherRestrictions>
         <description>
            <string language="x-t-cc-url">Licence text goes gere</string>
         </description>
      </rights>
   </lom>
</metadata>

 <metadata>
   <schema>http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM</schema>
   <lom xmlns="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/lomv1.0/lomLoose.xsd">
      <general>
         <title>
            <string language="es">Title goes here</string>
         </title>
         <description>
            <string language="es">Description goes here</string>
         </description>
         <keyword>
            <string language="en">a_nice_keyword</string>
         </keyword>
      </general>    
   </lom>
</metadata>
```

We see that lom is defined twice.

In my XSLT file, I when I use following namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:lom="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM/imslode/ilox/any/rights"
```

I manage to parse the elements of the first part using identifiers as follows, e.g.

```
lom:rights/lom:cost/lom:value
```

and same goes for the second case when I use the following namespace declaration

```
xmlns:lom="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM"
```

with identifiers such as:

```
lom:general/lom:description/lom:string
```

I do not seem to be able to parse / transform both at once.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two namespace declarations, with different prefixes - for example:

```
xmlns:lom="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM/imslode/ilox/any/rights"
xmlns:lom2="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM"
```

Then you can use a path like:

```
metadata[1]/lom:lom/lom:rights/lom:cost/lom:value
```

to select elements in the first branch, and:

```
metadata[2]/lom2:lom/lom2:general/lom2:description/lom2:string
```

to select elements in the other branch.

Comment: Definitely the right approach, but I'd consider `lom` and `lomRights`, to have more meaningful prefixes (calling the namespace with the more specialized purpose by the un-suffixed name is a bit misleading, after all). Perhaps `lom` and `lomR`, if terseness is at more of a premium.